# Precompiled Headers with ProC

Tags: c++, sql, oracle11g, oracle-pro-c

I am trying to use Pro*C with C++ to access an SQL database. The problem I am having is when trying to use a precompiled header in the .pc file. The ProC compiler puts the header after it has defined a macro which breaks visual studio. 
Is there a way to force the ProC to generate the CPP with the precompiled header first before the generated SQL structures?

Answer (score 0):

Just switch off precompiled headers for that .pc-file. Pro*C is dumb.

Comment: My question is trying to figure out HOW to use precomp headers